# Definir uma função com diferentes quantidades de argumentos

Tags: haskell

Existe algum motivo para que esta função:

```
foo f x y = f x y
foo x y = (+) x y
```

Retorne este erro?

> Equations for `foo' have different numbers of arguments

Por que o Haskell não permite esse comportamento?

Answer (score 3):

Perceba que no primeiro caso você tem 3 argumentos (f, x, y), e no segundo você tem 2 argumentos (somente x e y).

Se você quis especializar a aplicação de f, então é melhor criar uma outra função. Ex:

```
foosum x y = foo (+) x y
```

Comment: Ou simplesmente `foosum = foo (+)` (já que as funções sofrem *curry* por padrão).

Comment: Eu sei que elas possuem quantidades diferentes de parâmetros. O que quero saber é o motivo disso não funcionar, a decisão de design que moldou esse aspecto da linguagem.

Comment: o motivo é poder usar funções parcialmente aplicadas